# How to Make NetBeans Treat .cpp Files as C++ Source Code?

Tags: c++, netbeans

While programming in NetBeans, I downloaded all the right compilers. C worked fine for me.

But now that I started working with C++, I realized that while opening a new source file C++ with the extension `.cpp` the NetBeans goes to the C compilers, and then can't find include such as `<iostream>` etc.

But when opening the file with the extension `.c++` the NetBeans does go to the right directory and does recognize everything C++ related. Is there any way to change that so that the extension `.cpp` will also go to the right directory?
Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, NetBeans does treat .cpp files as C++ source code. The file extension mappings are configurable, so it is possible that they are different or corrupt on your machine. To change them do the following:

1. Select **Tools->Options**
2. Click the **C/C++** category.
3. Click the **Other** tab
4. Verify that "cpp" is in the C++ File Extensions list. If it is missing, add it.
5. Verify that "cpp" is *not* in the C File Extensions list. If it is present, remove it.
6. Click OK
7. Maybe restart NetBeans

Comment: Step 5 was the important one for me, cpp was defined (somehow?) in C source file extensions.  BTW, you can override the tool used by a specific file by selecting <file>->Properties from the project view and selecting the "Tool" on the General Tab - in my case the file.cpp file was pulling in the C Tool